# Pointer refer different values

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I got a problem while solving a beginner c++ challenge in hackerrank.
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/variable-sized-arrays/problem

The challenge require me to create an array of int array which simply is a 2d array, but the order of input constraints is so bad that I cannot make it. Suddenly, it pops up to me an idea of creating an array of pointers `*arrA` that each element refers `&arrB[0]` of its sub-array `arrB`.

**Note:** It is similar to `vector<vector<int>>` but I would not use `vector` here.

```
int main() {
    int n, q, k, i, j;
    cin >> n >> q;
    
    int *arr[n];
    for (int l = 0; l < n; l++) {
        cin >> k;
        int arr_i[k];
        for (int m = 0; m < k; m++) {
            cin >> arr_i[m];
        }
        arr[l] = &arr_i[0];
        cout << *arr[l] << " " << arr[l] << endl;
    }
    // after 2 loop, it prints
    // 1 0x7fff17940030
    // 2 0x7fff17940020
    
    for (int l = 0; l < q; l++) {
        cin >> i >> j;
        cout << *arr[l] << " " << arr[l] << endl;
    }
    
    // after 2 loop, it prints
    // random integer(eg: 395575472) 0x7fff17940030
    // random integer(eg: 922493088 ) 0x7fff17940020
    return 0;
}
```

The constraints are:

```
2 2           // n q
3 1 5 4       // k k[0] k[1] k[2]
5 2 2 8 9 3   // k k[0] k[1] k[2] k[3] k[4]
0 1           // i j
1 3           // i j
```

Back to the problem, the first loop prints exactly what i need. But in the second loop, the values are missing though the address are the same. I have search many stackoverflow question but none of them meets my needs.

*Can someone explain this to me. Many thanks !!!*

Comment: `int *arr[n];` is a VLA and not standard C++. Use `std::vector`. Furthermore, `int arr_i[k];` is a temporary object. So it's destroyed at the end of the scope. Your pointers point to non existing objects.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `std::vector`?

Comment: You're adding addresses of temporary variables to your main array, so each time they fall out of scope you get *garbage*. This could be fixed by using an array and `push_back`. `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` can accept entire rows with `push_back`.

Comment: Why exactly would you not use `vector<vector<int>>`? Right now you're using error-prone techniques and non-standard extansions.

Comment: @fabian Some compilers allow it, but it is non-standard.

Comment: Using vector make it an easy challlenge so i would like to try a bit in array.

Comment: Well, that's just asking for problems... "Driving with eyes open is easy, so I try to drive with my eyes closed"...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP seems to be doing things wrong on purpose.

Comment: I didn’t ask how solve this challenge, the solutions are already on hackerrank. I just try to configure out why the values of pointers are changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope for `int arr_i[k];` is the first loop, and while it's fine to take it's address with `arr[l] = &arr_i[0];` those addresses are out of scope when you dereference them in the 2nd loop.

Comment: Though i got the address of the local array. Wouldn’t it be the same address to access it?

Comment: The addresses do not change (as your example shows) but the content they reference changed.  Deference a stray pointer may result in a segfault, garbage data, or happen to have the data you expect.   The 2nd loop variable, l, might be allocated on the stack overwriting the data, or the function calls involved in cin/cout might have their arguments or return addresses in there now.

Comment: Thanks for your clearly explanation. I understand it finally.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ way to have variable sized arrays is [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). And you can have a vector-of-vectors.
Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    int nrOfVectors, q /* what is q?*/;
    std::cin >> nrOfVectors >> q;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vecvec(nrOfVectors);
    for(auto& vec : vecvec) {
        int nrOfElements;
        std::cin >> nrOfElements;
        vec.reserve(nrOfElements);
        std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), nrOfElements, back_inserter(vec));
    }
}
```

edit:
An array solution has no added value (actually makes thing unnecessarily complex and error-prone), but whatever

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>


int main() {
    int nrOfVectors, q /* what is q?*/;
    std::cin >> nrOfVectors >> q;
    std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<int[]>[]> vecvec(new std::unique_ptr<int[]>[nrOfVectors]);
    for (int i = 0; i < nrOfVectors; ++i) {
        int nrOfElements;
        std::cin >> nrOfElements;
        auto vec = new int[nrOfElements];
        for (int j = 0; j < nrOfElements; ++j) {
            std::cin >> vec[j];
        }
        vecvec[i].reset(vec);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to try a bit in using array since vector make this challenge so easy to solve.

Comment: @iamphduc Are you hearing youself? "I would like to try a bit in using array since vector make this challenge so easy to solve." And yet you come here for an answer... Don't make life hard on yourself.

Comment: Just trynna practice on array and figurate how things work. Anyway thank you for spending time on my question.